# Heroku app: Using both a requirements.txt file and .yml file

Tags: python, heroku, streamlit

Hi I am building a heroku app and I have three files for requirements:

`requirements.txt`:

```
gunicorn
pyyaml
seaborn
imageio
streamlit
imageio[ffmpeg]
xarray
```

`environment.yml`:

```yaml
name: eco-tech-h2gam
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - regionmask
  - cartopy
  - cdsapi
```

The syntax in my .yml file is correct

`heroku.yml`:

```yaml
    build:
      config: environment.yml
```

The dependencies in the `environment.yml` file are not installed any ideas?

Here is my setup.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set UTF-8 encoding
export PYTHONUTF8=1

# Install Miniconda (replace with the appropriate URL for your platform)
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh
bash miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda
rm miniconda.sh

# Add Miniconda to the PATH and initialize conda
export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
conda init bash

# Update conda and create a Conda environment
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
conda env create -f environment.yml

# Activate the Conda environment
conda activate eco-tech-h2gam

conda install --yes --file environment.yml

# Install your Conda dependencies (replace with your actual dependencies)

# (Optional) Install additional Python dependencies using pip
pip install -r requirements.txt

# Your other setup commands go here

# Create Streamlit config files
mkdir -p ~/.streamlit/

echo "\
[general]\n\
email = \"ludovic.giraud@essec.edu\"\n\
" > ~/.streamlit/credentials.toml

echo "\
[server]\n\
headless = true\n\
enableCORS=false\n\
port = $PORT\n\
" > ~/.streamlit/config.toml
```

and here is my procfile:

```
web: sh setup.sh && conda activate eco-tech-h2gam && streamlit run app.py
```

I also tried

```
web: sh setup.sh && source $HOME/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate eco-tech-h2gam && streamlit run app.py
```

I get the following error:

```
(eco-tech-h2gam) C:\Users\ludov\Bureau\eco-tech-h2gam>heroku logs --tail
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 8.7.1.
2024-01-04T19:46:01.515564+00:00 app[web.1]: Python runtime state: core initialized
2024-01-04T19:46:01.515583+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Also I launch the subprocesses using subrocess is my app.py file:

```
import streamlit as st
import base64
import os, glob, shutil
import platform
import subprocess
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date


class app():

    def __init__(self, sys, work_dir):
        self.sys = sys
        self.work_dir = work_dir   

    def get_latest_gif(self, folder_path):
        gifs = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.gif'))
        latest_gif = max(gifs, key=os.path.getctime)
        return latest_gif
    
    def return_path_to_gif(self, pollutant):
        if self.sys == "Windows":
            mypath = self.work_dir + "\\forecast\\fr\\" + pollutant + "\\"
        else:
            mypath = self.work_dir + "/forecast/fr/" + pollutant +"/"
        return mypath
       
    def display_gifs(self):

        os.chdir(self.return_path_to_gif("PM2.5"))


        dateoffile = pd.to_datetime(self.get_latest_gif(self.return_path_to_gif("PM2.5")).split("_concentration-")[1].split(".")[0],dayfirst = False)
        print(pd.Timestamp(date.today())  - dateoffile)
        if(pd.Timestamp(date.today())  - dateoffile > pd.Timedelta("1 Days")):
            print(pd.Timestamp(date.today())  - dateoffile)
            print("IN HERE")
            if self.sys == "Windows":
                subprocess.run("python " + self.work_dir + "\\DownloadCAMSforecast.py")
                subprocess.run("python " +  self.work_dir + "\\maps.py")
            else:
                subprocess.run(["python", self.work_dir + "/DownloadCAMSforecast.py"])
                subprocess.run(["python", self.work_dir + "/maps.py"])

        file_1 = open(self.get_latest_gif(self.return_path_to_gif("PM2.5")), "rb")
        contents = file_1.read()
        data_url1 = base64.b64encode(contents).decode("utf-8")
        file_1.close()

        file_2 = open(self.get_latest_gif(self.return_path_to_gif("PM10")), "rb")
        contents = file_2.read()
        data_url2 = base64.b64encode(contents).decode("utf-8")
        file_2.close()

        file_3 = open(self.get_latest_gif(self.return_path_to_gif("CO")), "rb")
        contents = file_3.read()
        data_url3 = base64.b64encode(contents).decode("utf-8")
        file_3.close()

        # HTML code to display gifs side by side
        html_code1 = f"""
            <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
                <img src="data:image/gif;base64,{data_url1}" alt="GIF 1" style="width: 28%;" loop = True>
                <img src="data:image/gif;base64,{data_url2}" alt="GIF 2" style="width: 28%;" loop = True>
                <img src="data:image/gif;base64,{data_url3}" alt="GIF 3" style="width: 28%;" loop = True>
            </div>
        """

        file_4 = open(self.get_latest_gif(self.return_path_to_gif("NO2")), "rb")
        contents = file_4.read()
        data_url4 = base64.b64encode(contents).decode("utf-8")
        file_4.close()

        file_5 = open(self.get_latest_gif(self.return_path_to_gif("SO2")), "rb")
        contents = file_5.read()
        data_url5 = base64.b64encode(contents).decode("utf-8")
        file_5.close()

        file_6 = open(self.get_latest_gif(self.return_path_to_gif("O3")), "rb")
        contents = file_6.read()
        data_url6 = base64.b64encode(contents).decode("utf-8")
        file_6.close()

        # HTML code to display gifs side by side
        html_code2 = f"""
            <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
                <img src="data:image/gif;base64,{data_url4}" alt="GIF 4" style="width: 28%;" loop = True>
                <img src="data:image/gif;base64,{data_url5}" alt="GIF 5" style="width: 28%;" loop>
                <img src="data:image/gif;base64,{data_url6}" alt="GIF 6" style="width: 28%;" loop>
            </div>
        """
        
        # Display the HTML code
        st.markdown(html_code1, unsafe_allow_html=True)
        st.markdown(html_code2, unsafe_allow_html=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp = app(platform.system(), os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) )
    MyApp.display_gifs()
```